# Bard's Tale: glitch on intel (15.04)

Tags: drivers, 15.04, games, intel, gpu-driver

There is a game called the Bard's Tale.

It used to run great for me on Ubuntu 14.10. But no more in 15.04.

My graphics card is an integrated Intel:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

You can see the glitch in question here:

[image: glitch]

There are those horrible black lines. I think it is where the shadow should be (something to do with alpha blending?). I have already set the game options to be as ugly as possible hehe (i.e. disable all effects).

I have all updates installed.

My question to you guys is: is there a known regression in the intel drivers? Can I maybe install the 14.10 driver or a new one?

Thanks!

ps: I have said Ubuntu. But I actually use Xubuntu, if it makes any difference.

Comment: The `lspci` output here didn't tell much about the graphic chip that you're using, try `lspci -nn | grep '\[03'`. Also, you may download the latest Intel graphic driver from: https://01.org/

Comment: @P.-H.Lin: `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)`

Comment: I am aware of the Intel drivers, thank you. They are not useful for 15.04: "At the moment the current intel graphics stack wouldn't add much - in particular, the kernel driver in 15.04 is already the same one that the graphics stack specifies" http://tinyurl.com/ow43jye

Comment: @P.-H.Lin there is no upgrade from the intel page. Do you know how I can downgrade them?